# Security related to retrieving record details using URL params

Tags: php, mysql, http

I have a script the fetches a record based on two values specified as parameters (two of them) in a URL. In this case, I need the file to be public and the assumption is that if the individual has the right value-pair combination (where x=1 && y=2) they have rightful access to the record.

This isn't banking or national security we're talking about here, but there are some privacy concerns.

I am especially concerned about these pages being indexed by spiders and becoming searchable, and also the concern of proxy servers minding Http traffic and a human going through someone's history. I am using meta tags to limit this, but I fear these will be ignored by some spiders.

What are your thoughts about the security of this method?

Are there any things I am missing that should scare me?

Are there any simple techniques to limit the security concerns with this method?

One idea was to use an if statement to limit access to the record for six hours from creation.

Thanks

Comment: If it's medical or personally identifiable information, you'd probably be best locking it off anyway.

Comment: What would be your recommendation for locking it off most effectively? Username/Password authentication isn't really an option. Time limit it? Nothing related to health, finances or private communication... just in that "who cares but still shouldn't be public" realm.

Comment: [Basic authentication](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/auth.html)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps. Its just a quick suggestion

```
$x = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST["x"]);
$y = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST["y"]);
```

// Since your only using numbers

```
$x = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","", $x);
$y = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","", $y);
```

// This will send them on their way

```
if ( empty( $y ) ) {
$domain = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"];
$domain_redirect = "http://".$domain."/index.php";
header("Location: $domain_redirect");
die;
}

$SQL = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE y = '$y' && x = '$x'";
$result = mysql_query( $SQL );
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ) ) {
$some_id = $row["some_id"];
}
```

// This will send them on their way again

```
if ( empty ( $some_id ) ){

$domain = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"];
$domain_redirect = "http://".$domain."/index.php";
header("Location: $domain_redirect");
die;
}
```